# Error while linking Cloud Revit file using ExternalResourceReference - The ExternalResourceReference is not in a format that's supported by its server

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-bim360

I would like to link a cloud model into another Revit Model for Revit 2021 and below. After lots of exploration, one of my colleague was able to use `ExternalResourceReference` to successfully link the model for one of the project in Revit 2020(below is the code). But when I try to use the same code in a Revit 2021 project I'm receiving the following error:

> The ExternalResourceReference (resourceReference) is not in a format that is supported by its server

```cs
var linkCloudPath = doc.GetCloudModelPath(); // the cloudpath of a BIM360 model
Guid linkedmodelguid = linkCloudPath.GetModelGUID();
Guid linkedprojectguid = linkCloudPath.GetProjectGUID();

Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary_ExternalResource = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
    {"LinkedModelModelId", modelGuid.ToString()},
    {"LinkedModelProjectId", projGuid.ToString()}
};

Dictionary<string, Guid> servers = new Dictionary<string, Guid>();

foreach (var service in ExternalServiceRegistry.GetServices())
{
    if (service.Name == "External Resource Service")
    {
        IList<Guid> server_ids = service.GetRegisteredServerIds();


        foreach (var server_id in server_ids)
        {
            servers.Add(service.GetServer(server_id).GetName(), server_id);
        }
    }
}

Guid BIM360ServerID = servers["BIM 360"];
ExternalResourceReference ERS = new ExternalResourceReference(BIM360ServerID, Dictionary_ExternalResource, "", "");
RevitLinkOptions options = new RevitLinkOptions(false);
LinkLoadResult result = RevitLinkType.Create(gcdoc, ERS, options); // error in this line
RevitLinkInstance.Create(gcdoc, result.ElementId);
```

There is no change in the code anywhere between 2020 & 2021.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I just needed to add region the dictionary `Dictionary_ExternalResource`

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary_ExternalResource = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
    {"LinkedModelRegion","US" }, // added this line
    {"LinkedModelModelId", modelGuid},
    {"LinkedModelProjectId", projGuid}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to check `ExternalResourceReference` by calling `RevitLinkType.GetExternalResourceReferences()` from the link type, which has been set to BIM 360 model, so that you can get all information required.

With my testing, the below format was returned. `ServerId` can be used from getting `ExternalServiceRegistry.GetServices()` int the same manner you have tried.

```
{
  "ServerId": "XXXXX",
  "ReferenceInformation": {
    "ForgeDmItemUrn": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:XXXXX",
    "ForgeDmProjectId": "b.XXXXX",
    "LinkedModelModelId": "XXXXX",
    "LinkedModelProjectId": "XXXXX",
    "LinkedModelRegion": "US"
  },
  "Version": "",
  "InSessionPath": "BIM 360://XXXXX"
}
```

Please note that there may have been some special-casing for cloud links.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this @Ryuji, I was able to solve the issue already. But this `RevitLinkType.GetExternalResourceReferences()` method helps a lot to understand the format of a reference.